# Styling the ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock and trying to style the dropdown from the ShareActionProvider, my current theme is Light.DarkActionbar. I can't seem to find the right style to change.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why my previous post was deleted.  This still has not been answered from what I can see, and I provided the answer to the general question of how to set the background of an ActionBar item, which may have been all he needed, or all that other people are looking for.